# How to block pop ups in geckofx

Tags: c#, browser, popup, geckofx

how I can block pop ups like "This page is asking to confirm that you want to leave..." in c# browser based on GeckoFX?

I found something like this and use it in constructor but it is not warking

```
private void InjectAlertBlocker()
    {
        GeckoHtmlElement head = browser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];
        GeckoElement scriptEl = browser.Document.CreateElement("script");
        string alertBlocker = "window.alert = function () { }";
        scriptEl.SetAttribute("text", alertBlocker);
        head.AppendChild(scriptEl);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the handler:

```
(function() {
  window.addEventListener("load", foo, false);

  function foo() {
    var u = "beforeunload";
    var v = unsafeWindow;
    if (v._eventTypes && v._eventTypes[u]) {
      var r=v._eventTypes[u];
      for(var s=0;s<r.length;s++) {
        v.removeEventListener(u,r[s],false);
      }
      v._eventTypes[u]=[];
    }
  } 

})();
```

Comment: it is java script function, how i can use it in c#?